# Create label in middle of scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey I want to create labels during runtime and delete them also. First I want my program to create a label when the view Did Load in the middle of my Scroll View.
 So far my viewDidLoad looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
inputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(0), nil];

UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(
                                                             (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.origin.x + (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.size.width / 2)),
                                                             (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.origin.y + (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.size.height / 2)),
                                                             0,0)];

label.text = [[inputArray lastObject] stringValue];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[labelArray addObject:(label)];
[_scrollViewForLabels addSubview:label];
```

But i can't see the 0 that should be displayed anywhere. Where could it be?

Comment: You create a label with width and height of 0,0 ... very probably at least *part* of the issue.

Comment: Change that line to: UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(
                                                             (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.origin.x + (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.size.width / 2)),
                                                             (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.origin.y + (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.size.height / 2)),
                                                             50,50)];

Comment: Add this >UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.origin.x + (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.size.width / 2)), (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.origin.y + (_scrollViewForLabels.frame.size.height / 2)), 50,50)]

and set center of label = center of scrollview.

with above add frame and contentsize equal to each other. if need not to scroll

Comment: Ok thx guys, but the Label doesn't show up in my NSMutableArray labelArray. I tried to change it already to                                              [labelArray addObject:((UILabel *) label)]; but it still doesn't show up in the Array

Comment: first create a label with some height and width

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the labels array before trying to add to it...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    inputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@(0), nil];

    // add this line
    labelArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    // the rest of your setup...
}
```

Comment: Makes Sense, Thanks.